# Web page that displays images in three different manners: cycling banner, random image display, and slide show

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, image, banner

I need help figuring out where my script went wrong. I am not understanding specifically what am I suppose to do to get my loop and array to work. I am not following these instructions at all.

**Instructions:** 
Web page that displays images in three different manners: cycling banner, random image display, and slide show. In the script section, create the following functions:

- cycle():
- select():
- doBack():
- doNext():
- startup(): calls the cycle() and select() functions.

**My attempt:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var imageArray  = new Array("lions.gif", "tigers.gif", "bears.gif", "ohmy.gif") ;
        var cycleIndex  = 0
          , randomIndex = 0
          , slideIndex  = 0
          , pictureIndex= 0
          ;
        //startup ()
        function cycle(cycleIndex)  {   
        cycleIndex++;
        if (cycleIndex == imageArray.length) {
        cycleIndex = 0;
        }
        document.getElementById("cycleBanner").src = imageArray[cycleIndex];

        {
            imageArray[0] = new Image() ; imageArray[0].src = "lions.gif"   ;
            imageArray[1] = new Image() ; imageArray[1].src = "tigers.gif"  ;
            imageArray[2] = new Image() ; imageArray[2].src = "bears.gif"   ;
            imageArray[3] = new Image() ; imageArray[3].src = "ohmy.gif"    ;
        // TODO: initialize the other three images in the array (indexes 1, 2, and 3)

            cycle () ;  // start the cycling banner
            select() ;  // start the random banner

            return ;
        }

        function cycle()
        {
        // TODO: set the source of the displayed cycling banner image to the 
        // next image in the image array - watch for 'wrap around'

        document.cycleBanner.src - imageArray[cycleIndex].src ;

        cycleIndex++ ;{
            setTimeout("cycle()",2000) ;  // refresh after 2 seconds
        }
            return ;
        }

        function select()
        {
        // TODO: set the source of the displayed random banner image to a 
        // random image in the image array

        function myFunction() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
        document.getElementById("ClickMe").innerHTML = x;
        }

        randomIndex++ ;
            setTimeout("select()",1000) ;

            return ;
        }

        function doBack()
        {
        // TODO: set the source of the displayed slide show image to the  
        // previous image in the image array, if there is one - if not, stay put


            return ;
        }

        function doNext()
        {
        // TODO: set the source of the displayed slide show image to the  
        // next image in the image array, if there is one - if not, stay put


            return ;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really rough start that I put together for you. My thoughts are that you would have one image `<img id="cycleBanner" src="" alt="">` where the source would be updated based off a list of sources. `init()`isn't necessary, but I was thinking on more of a class level which wouldn't be a bad idea. You could consolidate some of these into one function and use a parameter for more conditional processing. Ex. `cycle(direction)` where direction would be `"prev" or "next"`. Hope this helps!

```
var imageSources = ["lions.gif", "tigers.gif", "bears.gif", "ohmy.gif"],
    imageIndex = 0,
    cycleTimer = null,
    imageElement = document.getElementById("cycleBanner");

//Inits the element to be the first image of our sources
function init(){
    imageElement.src = imageSources[0];
    updateImageElement();
}

//Updates the image element to be the source of the current index
function updateImageElement() {
    imageElement.src = imageSources[imageIndex];
}

//Updates the image element to the next source. If the index is out of bounds, it loops back to the beginning.
function nextImage(){
    if(imageIndex + 1 > imageSources.length){
        imageIndex = 0;
    } else {
        imageIndex++;
    }

    updateImageElement();
}

//Updates the image element to the prev source. If the index is out of bounds, it loops back to the end.
function prevImage() {
    if(imageIndex - 1 < 0){
        imageIndex = imageSources.length - 1;
    } else {
        imageIndex--;
    }

    updateImageElement();
}

function randomImage(){
    imageIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageSources.length);
    updateImageElement();
}

function cycleForward(){
    clearTimeout(cycleTimer);
    cycleTimer = setTimeout(nextImage(), 2000);
}

function cycleBackward(){
    clearTimeout(cycleTimer);
    cycleTimer = setTimeout(prevImage(), 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I have to use the following functions & I am unsure of how to add them in the script:: •cycle(): 
•select():
•doBack(): 
•doNext(): 
•startup(): calls the cycle() and select() functions.